# Tomcat on windows log shipping to logstash

Tags: windows, tomcat, redis, logstash

I am trying to configure log shipping/ consolidation using logstash. My tomcat servers run on Windows. I am running into a few problems with my configuration - Tomcat on windows, logging using log4j, redis consolidator/ elasticsearch/ logstash/ kibana running on a single linux server.

1. Fewer log shippers available on Windows. It looks like nxlog does not work with redis out of the box. So, I have reverted to using logstash to ship. I would like to learn what others prefer to use
2. Rather use custom appenders I would rather have tomcat use log4j to log to file and then feed the file as input to be shipped to Redis. I don't want to the log formats.
   No json-event format for me - http://spredzy.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/monitor-your-cluster-of-tomcat-applications-with-logstash-and-kibana/. I can't seem to get the right file config in the shipper.conf

Any sample config for log4j files - fed to logstash via redis would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently writing a Java library to send logs to Logstash using ZeroMQ (no central redis broker required).
Disclaimer: it's not quite perfect yet, but may be worth keeping an eye on.
https://github.com/stuart-warren/logit

You can setup the standard juli log configuration (or log4j if you are using that), plus with the tomcat-valve jar you can send access logs as well by configuring the server.xml.

It does however send it in json-event format by default.
I'm confused as to why you wouldn't want to save all the processing on the Logstash server? You can (and currently probably should) log to file in standard format as well.

logging.properties file.

```
# "handlers" specifies a comma separated list of log Handler 
# classes. These handlers will be installed during VM startup.
# Note that these classes must be on the system classpath.
# By default we only configure a ConsoleHandler, which will only
# show messages at the INFO and above levels.

handlers= com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender
# handlers= com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# Default global logging level.
# This specifies which kinds of events are logged across
# all loggers. For any given facility this global level
# can be overriden by a facility-specific level.
# Note that the ConsoleHandler also has a separate level
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.

.level=INFO

# Limit the messages that are printed on the console to INFO and above.

com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender.level=INFO
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender.socketType=PUSHPULL
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender.endpoints=tcp://localhost:2120
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender.bindConnect=CONNECT
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender.linger=1000
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender.sendHWM=1000
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.ZmqAppender.layout=com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.Layout

com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.Layout.layoutType=logstashv1
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.Layout.detailThreshold=WARNING
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.Layout.tags=tag1,tag2,tag3
com.stuartwarren.logit.jul.Layout.fields=field1:value1,field2:value2,field3:value3

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

server.xml

```
<Valve className="com.stuartwarren.logit.tomcatvalve.ZmqAppender"
           layout="com.stuartwarren.logit.tomcatvalve.Layout"
           socketType="PUSHPULL"
           endpoints="tcp://localhost:2120"
           bindConnect="CONNECT"
           linger="1000"
           sendHWM="1000"
           layoutType="logstashv1"
           iHeaders="Referer,User-Agent"
           oHeaders=""
           cookies=""
           tags="tag1,tag2,tag3"
           fields="field1:value1,field2:value2,field3:value3" />
```